# Prevent mobile keyboard from opening when <input /> mount in react javascript and enable on click

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a modal window that is opened when a user clicks a button. This modal window has an `<input type="text" />` component.

When the modal window is mounted the mobile keyboard is automatically opened and the focus is set on this one Input.

I am enabling and disabling the readonly or disabled html attribute but it forces the user to double click or triple click on the input for the mobile keyboard to be visible.

How can I prevent the mobile keyboard from opening when an Input is mounted and how do I display the mobile keyboard when the users single-click on that Input component?

The code below is what I have right now, it forces the users on mobile to double click on the Input component to display the keyboard. Double clicking is not user friendly since it moves the scroll position around or displays the Select All, Copy, Paste, etc mobile tooltip instead of displaying the mobile keyboard.

```
<input
  type="text"
  readonly={this.state.isInputReadOnly}
  onClick={this.onInputClick}
  onChange={this.onInputChange}
  value={this.state.inputValue}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

When modal opens, instead of focusing on input, focus on some other element in modal, say some span element.. This should prevent keyboard from opening.